# Implement a Rate Limiter in Simulnk without using the in-built Rate Limiter block

Tags: matlab, simulink, rate-limiting, simulink-library, symfony-ratelimiter

Implement a Rate Limiter in Simulnk without using the in-built Rate Limiter block. Use the basic blocks(any block other than Rate Limiter) to design a rate Limiter. Rising Slew Rate is 3 and Falling Slew rate is -5.

Design a Rate Limiter in Simulink using Basic Blocks in Simulink of Rising Fle Rate of 3 and Falling Slew rate of -5. The rate is calculated as Rate = [u(i) - y(i-1)]/[t(i) - t(i-1)] and if the slew rate is greater than the rising slew rate , then the output is calculated as y(i) = delta(t) . R +  y(i-1), and if the slew rate is less than the falling slew rate, then the output is y(i) = delta(t) . F + y(i-1) where R is the Rising Slew Rate and F is the Falling Slew Rate.